# Can we get a CHAOSer in here?

Tags: discussion

I'm finding that cooking is degrading into one of the grammatically worst stackexchanges.  Is it possible to get a CHAOS member in here?

If not, can we tag our edits somehow so that we can do it on a volunteer basis without clogging the Mod queue?

Comment: Can you point to specific examples? "Grammatically worst stackexchanges" sounds like quite a stretch to me. I dare say that we're actually better than most; at least 4 in 5 question titles are actually *questions*. Also keep in mind that CHAOS is not a cleanup crew, they're a promotional team and site cleanup is an occasional small part of that (so again, we'd need to demonstrate a real need for that kind of effort).

Comment: Look at my last 5 edits.

Comment: I see. I'm still not sure I see the problem though; first of all, edits don't clog up the mod queue, and second, it looks like most of these edits are on recent questions, which doesn't even hurt the front page. I'll routinely do 5 or more retags in the span of a few minutes when I get home from work; it's not really a big deal.

Comment: That's because I'm working on the obvious first.  What happens when I get to page 10?

Comment: Were you planning to go through 10 pages? It's great if you were, but most of the time I've observed that people mostly stick to cleaning up what's on the front page and only edit a small handful of older questions at any given time; one tends to burn out quickly after spending several hours correcting spelling and grammar. I'm still not convinced that the situation is *so* bad that hundreds of questions need to be fixed right now...

Comment: Well, consider it a labour of love.   I would like to clean up a bit.  I'll get there eventually.

Comment: Some of us *like* editing for grammar. I've been slightly reluctant, though, because unlike english.stackexchange.com, grammar isn't really on-topic here, so if a post is understandable... but anyway.

Comment: @Marti: I don't see any reason to hesitate, if they're good edits. It's not like we have problems with too many edits right now. As long as they're not trivial edits like correcting "it's" to "its" while the rest of the post is still incomprehensible (yes those do happen).

Comment: Also, there's at least one or two CHAOSers that are regularly around, but their psi disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I am your primary CHAOS agent now, as [Katey](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/7082/katey) has been kidnapped by Gaming to help with their recent promotions.

CHAOS is not doing any massive title clean-up sprees anymore; you'll notice that we haven't had mod diamonds for months now, so we're more or less just regular users on the sites. [Abby](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/6728/abby-t-miller) wrote [a blog post on our recent shift in tactics](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/the-art-of-organizing-chaos/), including the forgoing of clean-up sprees. Most of the sites we're working with now do not require them, and our time is really better spent coming up with promotion ideas, wooing influencers in the industry, and trying to recruit new users.

I encourage you to continue making edits to questions and answers that you feel need a little help. Approving an edit is not a very time-consuming task for moderators, and you'll continue to accrue points for the edits you make. Don't worry about overloading them; if they get overwhelmed, they can let us know and we'll either assign an SE employee to help temporarily or have an election to get an additional mod for the site.

If everyone does a few edits here and there, I think we'll be able to maintain the quality of the site just fine. I actually don't see a lot of egregiously incorrect posts; I don't think it's a problem worth worrying about TOO much.

Comment: Did you ever have diamonds? I thought you had pitchforks.

Comment: @Aaronut For about a week ;) [during our massive title clean-up spree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100359/166017) so that we didn't bog down mod queues with hundreds of edits in the span of a day or two. (We also had a special temporary mode for us to not have our edits bump questions.) The pitchforks didn't denote special powers, they were just a way to let people know we were this new team of people popping up on the network. We've since [gotten rid of them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110963/did-everyone-on-chaos-get-fired-or-something-what-happened-to-their-pitchforks).